# GENERATED keyword as column title in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a table with GENERATED as column in MySQL version 5.7.16. When I try below query it is giving error:

```
create table madhu (RECORDID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, GENERATED INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Below is the error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED INTEGER NOT NULL)' at line 1    0.000 sec

It looks GENERATED is reserved key word. Is there away to have GENERATED as column? If I change the column it works anyway.

Comment: use backticks for that but better to avoid reserved words

Comment: It may be working in 5.6.* version but i am looking very specific in 5.7.*

Answer (score 0):

To escape reserved keywords use backticks or choose a different column name.

```
create table madhu
(
   RECORDID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
   `GENERATED` INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I can't choose different name .. as these column name is generated. Is there any server level config to overwrite this behavior. May be some config in my.cnf ?

Comment: I doubt it since the query parser does not understand your query with a reserved word at the wrong place.